# In Javascript, given value, find name from Object literal

Tags: javascript

I'm new JavaScript and trying to find out an easier way to find name given a value from object literal.

e.g.

```
var cars ={ Toyata: ['Camry','Prius','Highlander'],
            Honda:  ['Accord', 'Civic', 'Pilot'],
            Nissan: ['Altima', 'Sentra', 'Quest']};
```

Given 'Accord', I want to get Honda from the object Cars.

Comment: What if another manufacturer has the same model? Let's say Chevrolet makes an Accord.

Comment: "an easier way" than what?  Why don't you post how you're doing it now?  By the way, there is probably no easier way, unless you can use a library that might assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to loop through, like this:

```
function getManufacturer(carName) {
    for(var key in cars) {
        if(cars.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           for(var i=0; i<cars[key].length; i++) {
              if(cars[key][i] == carName) return key;
           }
        }
    }
    return "Not found";
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/q3t3u/), for the same of working cross-browser, this ignores the existence of [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) since IE doesn't have it...[that version would look like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/q3t3u/1/):

```
function getManufacturer(carName) {
    for(var key in cars) {
        if(cars.hasOwnProperty(key) && cars[key].indexOf(carName) != -1) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return "Not found";
}
```

Comment: Just curious... is the cars.hasOwnProperty redundant?

Comment: @SB - nope, not if someone messed with the Object prototype...better to be safe IMO

Comment: @SB: At this point it is mostly cargo cult programming. The theory is that it is safe to do it but not necessarily safe not to do it. See the footnote to my answer for possible reasons why it may not be safe to do it. Hint: hasOwnProperty will tell you if the property is inherited or not.

Comment: @slebetman - you don't have to inherit from anything out of the ordinary, not matter what you inherit from `Object`, and it can have additional properties added to its prototype.  What if someone added a property that's a function, or a string, or...? Without it you're *assuming* everything there is an array that isn't a *safe* assumption.

Comment: @Nick: I mention what happens to that in my footnote: you have to do a hasOwnProperty check and I feel sorry for you. My assumption is that it is a raw javascript object not inheriting for anything. If it is an array then it is not a raw javascript object but inherits for Array instead so you'd have to do a hasOwnProperty check (again mentioned in my answer).

Comment: @Nick: Personally I would say using any library/code that modifies base objects is not *safe*. Monkey-patching your own code to compensate is just that: a patch.

Comment: @slebetman - I think you missed my point, you're *assuming* no one messed with it, that's not a safe assumption...you may be in control of the entire page, libraries and prior code, some developers aren't.  If you don't know for *sure*, check. I *strongly* disagree it's "monkey patching", it's being safe, in all cases for *very* little cost.  I think you're making judgements about other environments with zero insight into them, people don't always control everything in the page...on larger projects, you rarely do.  My point is you shouldn't *assume* things, almost ever.

Comment: @slebetman - Step back and look at your argument, you're saying "use this, it's much simpler"....oh, only if these assumptions are true and that never changes...you think that's the best way to go about things, especially when providing samples to others?  I don't disagree that `.hasOwnProperty()` *shouldn't* be needed, just your analysis/dismissal of it and *proper* reasons for using it.

Comment: This is perfect. I used the one without the use of ".indexOf" and it works well for me.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Nick: I sed the first function (without the indexOf) and it works perfrectly for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nick: I didn't say it was simpler. Simply that it was faster. Both our answers can be written with and without hasOwnProperty. Admit it, you even wrote yours without then later added it without explaining why. I explain why you might need it (again I made NO assumptions - I explain, since I believe it is better for one to know why a piece of code is needed than simply copying).

Comment: @slebetman - "Admit it, you even wrote yours without then later added it without explaining why"....no, it had it from the start, it was never added.  I believe it should be there, and it always has been, you'll note there's no revision history on the answer above, and both versions of the demo have it.

Comment: -- continued: The simplicity of not including hasOwnProperty in code illustrating an algoritm is a separate issue of showing what's happening in the clearest possible way - for the same reason I didn't encapsulate my code in a function - to remove as much 'noise' as possible from the discussion. In fact, I even noted WHERE in the code a hasOwnProperty check may need to be implemented as a hint - someone who knows about it will get a quick hint how to modify the code and someone who does not know about it will get a hint of what to google for further info.

Comment: @Nick: That was weird. I swear I saw you original answer without it. Deja-vu?

Comment: @slebetman - I have a few thousand other answers, probably just remember something similar :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing this once, then use a function like the one given by Bobby. If you're going to be doing this multiple times then I'd suggest creating a reverse mapping of cars to manufacturers:

```
var manufacturers = {};

// create a map of car models to manufacturers:
for (var manf in cars) {
    /* see note below */

    for (var i=0; i<cars[manf].length; i++) {
        manufacturers[cars[manf][i]] = manf;
    }
}

// Now referencing the manufacturers is 
// a very fast hash table lookup away:

var model = 'Accord';
alert(manufacturers[model]);
```

note for those with itchy downvoting fingers: For objects that don't inherit anything as given in the OP a hasOwnProperty check here is unnecessary. For objects that do inherit it depends on the programmer. If you want composability via inheritance then a hasOwnProperty check is exactly what you DONT want. If you don't care about inheritance then use a hasOwnProperty check but if so you would not be inheriting in the first place which would make a hasOwnProperty check unnecessary. In the rare case where you are forced to create the object via inheritance but don't want to check the parent's attributes then you should do a hasOwnProperty check. Of course, if you use a library like Prototype.js that insists on modifying the Object object then I feel sorry for you because you are forced to do a hasOwnProperty check.

Comment: This wouldn't have the same result, it should be noted that if 2 manufacturers made the same car, this would return the *last* one, rather than the *first*, both positions being relative to object property order...which isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @Nick: Ah, but if we are talking about cars here then it is highly likely that the model names would be unique. Similarly, other problem domains may also have this property. Besides, object property have random order (at least in theory) so talking about "first" or "last" makes no sense if you don't first sort the manufacturer name. (tested it, on firefox at least object property does not necessarily come up in creation order when doing a for..in loop, this is not PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a separate mapping of models to manufacturers.

```
var cars ={ Toyata: ['Camry','Prius','Highlander'],
            Honda:  ['Accord', 'Civic', 'Pilot'],
            Nissan: ['Altima', 'Sentra', 'Quest']};

var models = {};
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
for (key in cars) {
    if (hasOwnProperty.call(cars, key)) {
        var i=0,l=cars[key].length,manufacturer=cars[key];
        while (i<l) {
            if ( ! hasOwnProperty.call(models, manufacturer)) {
                models[manufacturer] = key;
            } else {
                // Throw an error, or change the value to an array of values
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More code: Yay!  Hope about one data structure enabling bi-directional (bidi) mapping of keys to values, and vice versa

Comment: @George -- forgive me for not understanding ... why do you suggest the data structure approach?  I fail to see how that would be better in this case. (I'm guessing that it's for re-usability).

Comment: Yes, for re-usability.  Maybe a custom object that encapsulates the original data structure and the one you propose.  But certainly some way of associating the two so they aren't in the global scope with no relationship to one another.