# In Javascript, given value, find value and filter on the specific value from Object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, object-literal

I should note I am not the best with Javascript/ajax/jquery. Anyway, I am in need of some assistance when it comes to checking an object to see if it contains a certain value based on an object literal. I am using the [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/) for a project I am working on. The library visualization I am using isn't using a true json object, but more of a javascript object literal. I'm having a hard time seeing if an item exists in my object.

I tried the [best answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432330/in-javascript-given-value-find-name-from-object-literal) after making changes to fit my code, however, it does not seem to work properly.

I've also tried a for..in loop which I know is frowned upon (plus I didn't get this to work as expected either)

Here is the object and its structure:

```
 myObj = {
    id: "190_0",
    name: "Pearl Jam",
    children: [{
        id: "306208_1",
        name: "Pearl Jam &amp; Cypress Hill",
        children: [{
            id: "84_2",
            name: "Cypress Hill",
            children: []
        },
        {
            id: "306208_3",
            name: "Alex"
        }]
    }]
};
```

[EDIT]
I am trying to get to "Alex" in this example, but everything I've attempted fails. I'd need it to look through the entire structure, so I can't have hard-coded selections (myObj.children[0].name....)

The end goal for my project is to be able to search for users whom have a specific skill set. So for example:

I want to search for the skillset C++, then show all the children of C++ (which would be people's names).
[/EDIT]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you trying to find alex? Like are you trying to find any object with `name=x` or any object with a property with value `x`

Comment: It should be `myObj.children[0].children[1].name`. Whether that answers your question I have no idea.

Comment: *I am trying to get to "Alex"*. This is not well defined. What if there are more than one "Alex"? Do you want to explore all tree of descendants? What if the object is recursive (some node has an ancestor as a child)?

Comment: This is just an example that I am trying to use. What I will actually be attempting to filter on in my implementation is a specific skill set.

For example, down the line I would want to search on C++ and then show all entries / objects under the C++ node.

Comment: You want to detect if the value appears _anywhere_ in the object?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Yes

Comment: for..in is only frowned upon when used to iterate over an array. It is the proper syntax to use to iterate over an object. The problem when using it with an array is, depending on the browser, it will also iterate over the prototype.

Comment: @Deadron finding it on the prototype is totally legit imo. It's still there if it's on the prototype.

Comment: Many of us come from languages where you can use a foreach on any collection/array so it is confusing, especially when it works in FF/Chrome.  I wasn't trying to suggest it was or was not legit though, it just merely is.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum since this is specific to searching an object literal for data, I don't think searching the prototype is appropriate. I'd imagine this is data extraction for the sake of displaying something for the end user, and I doubt they care about the inner workings of the object.

Comment: @Bubbles It's a perfectly fine use case to read data from the prototype. `var a = {x:3,y:6};var b = Object.create(a);` - if you ask me it seems perfectly reasonable to say `b` has a property with the value 6 even though it's in its prototype. Also, I'm sorry if my comment on my answer came off as harsh and I don't understand why you deleted your comment and answer (it _was_ missing a `return false` to terminate the `$.each` in the `if` but that's nothing major).

Comment: It seems to me that you might want to pre-process your objects before you use them. Maybe even separate the children into a different data structure. Ending up with [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/QcKfg/) isn't a bad plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the clarification here is a recursive way to check that:

Here is a small implementation

```
function contains(obj,what){
    if(obj === what){ 
        return true;
    }
    if(typeof obj!== "object" || obj === null){
        return false;
    }
    for(var i in obj){
        if(contains(obj[i],what)){
            return true;
        }
    }
   return false;
}
```

This works in all browsers new and old and has no dependencies. Once again annotated:

```
function contains(obj,what){
    if(obj === what){ // if the object is what we're looking for - return it
        return true;
    }
    // if it's not what we're looking for and it's not an object return it
    if(typeof obj!== "object" || obj === null){
        return false;
    }
    for(var i in obj){ // check if it's any of its properties
        if(contains(obj[i],what)){
            return true; // found it in a child
        }
    }
   return false; // did not find it anywhere.
}
```

Also, obligatory one liner:

```
function contains(obj,what){
    return (obj === what)||((typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null) &&  Object.keys(obj).some(function(el){return contains(obj[el],what);}));
}
```

Comment: @Bubbles Seriously? Look at your jQuery code and look at my native one?  Even if we ignore the one line golfed version which is shorter. The Native JS version is _a lot_ more readable than the jQuery one, it's more reusable. I don't buy the "aweful type system" bit - if you code in a language you _have_ to know it, lack of knowledge of the language typesystem is not an excuse for including an 80K LoC library. Learn the language instead.